# how to remove trailing line from every file with our renaming the fuel

Tags: sed

Hi I use the following code to remove the trailing lines from a file. But is there anyway I can run this on 2000 files inside a folder with out renaming them ? thanx in advance

```
sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba'
```

Comment: If the files have a pattern like for example `myfile_number`, you can do `sed .... myfile_*`.

Comment: yes but it outputs the result but not delete the line in the file. ?

Comment: For that, you need to use `sed -i`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "" -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba' YourFile
```

if it is in same folder with a pattern to select id like *.txt, replace YourFile by the shell pattern, if other selection pass each file name via a pre selection like find or a while read from a stream/file input

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to list the files that you need, and then run `sed` on each on them. This version uses the -i option to modify the files in place:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I % sed -i  -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba' %
```